# Join multiple tables when using a generic repository in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I have a .Net Solution with multiple projects for the layers which are as follows.

- Business (solution folder)

  - Core (project)
  - Interfaces (project)
- Data (solution folder)

  - Data (project)
- Presentation (solution folder)

  - AdminPanel (project)
- Shared (solution folder)

  - Common (project)

I have implemented the generic repository pattern with IoC layer using Unity i.e. Microsoft.Practices.Unity. Everything works great except when I want to do multi table simple or complex joins. I have tried many different ways. I have gone through every single existing thread here on SO regarding joins in repository but none of them are helpful in what I need.

**Here's my repository class.**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        protected BuyatimeshareModel Context { get; private set; }

        public Repository(IContextFactory contextFactory)
            : this(contextFactory.Get())
        {
        }

        protected Repository(BuyatimeshareModel context)
        {
            context.Database.Log = message => { Common.Logging.Log(message); };
            Context = context;
        }
        IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet
        {
            get
            {
                return Context.Set<TEntity>();
            }
        }
        public TEntity Add(TEntity instance)
        {
            DbSet.Add(instance);
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return instance;
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity instance)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(instance);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> All()
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Query() { IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet; return query.ToList(); }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable().Count();
        }

        public int Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable().Count(predicate);
        }

        public bool Exists(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable().Any(predicate);
        }
    }
```

**Here's my IoC layer.**

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        IUnityContainer container;

        public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (controllerType == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerType");

                if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                        "Type requested is not a controller: {0}", controllerType.Name),
                        "controllerType");

                return container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }

        public static void Configure()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            /*string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;*/
            container.RegisterType<IContextFactory, ContextFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())//, new InjectionConstructor(connectionString))
                     .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                     .RegisterType<IAdminService, AdminService>()

                     .RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new UnityControllerFactory(container));
        }
    }
```

**And finally here's my service layer where I'm trying to query some data from the repository layer.**

```
public class AdminService : IAdminService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<press_releases> pressReleasesRepo;
        private readonly IRepository<tblads> adsRepo;
        private readonly IRepository<tblresorts> resortsRepo;

        public AdminService(IRepository<press_releases> _pressReleasesRepo, IRepository<tblads> _adsRepo, IRepository<tblresorts> _resortsRepo)
        {
            pressReleasesRepo = _pressReleasesRepo;
            adsRepo = _adsRepo;
            resortsRepo = _resortsRepo;
        }
        public List<press_releases> Test()
        {
            var data = pressReleasesRepo.FindAll(p => p.pr_id > 0);
            var data1 =
                (from a in adsRepo.Query()
                    join r in resortsRepo.Query() on a.resort_id equals r.resort_id
                    where a.ad_id == 413
                    select new
                    {
                        OwnerId = a.owner_id,
                        ResortName = r.name,
                        AdId = a.ad_id,
                        AskingPrice = a.askingPriceInt
                    }).ToList();

            var model = data.ToList();
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Now here we have two queries. **data** and **data1**

**data** is simply querying one single table with a criteria and its returning results as expected. All good here.

But, in **data1**, it is also technically returning exactly the end result that I want BUT I also have a raw SQL logger in place to see what's happening behind the scenes and what it's doing is to query both ads table and resorts table separately using a **select *** equivalent statement and then when the results return from both tables, it's applying the joins within memory and returning the result after filtering through the where clause. So basically its scanning through around 100000 rows even though I have join and where clause in place and in the end, it returns one single row with ad id 413.

One thing to note down is that I'm calling **Query** method of the repository class while doing the join for **data1** which is returning an IEnumerable. I was not able to change it to IQueryable because then an exception was being thrown having some message like the linq query has references to different contexts.

Can anyone guide me to modify this code so that I can apply real sql joins between the repositories or if there's a way to modify this code by adding a middle layer to act as a bridge. I need something to go forward from this point. I've been looking everywhere but no avail. I'm sure that I'm not the first one ever in this world who could have this problem. There definitely would be others having similar issue and may be someone who have found a real way.

My tools and technologies are as follows.

- Visual Studio 2013
- .Net framework 4.0
- MySQL Database
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.4
- MySQL Connector 6.9.6
- Entity Framework 6
- Windows 10 Pro x64

Please let me know if there's anything that I might have missed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

**Here's the ContextFactory class**

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
    {
        private bool _isDisposed;
        private SomeModel _context;

        public ContextFactory()
        { }

        public SomeModel Get()
        {
            _context = new SomeModel();
            return _context;
        }

        ~ContextFactory()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_isDisposed && disposing && (_context != null))
                _context.Dispose();

            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method you have in your repository which you are using in your data1.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Query() { IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet; return query.ToList(); }
```

Whenever you hit '.ToList()' it will hit the database.

If you want to create the query first and then execute then use 'DbSet' property of your repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have already mentioned this in my question earlier that I was aware that I was returning an IEnumerable type instead of IQueryable i.e. immediate query vs deferred. But it was giving me an error of having different contexts. So, I was not able to skip the .ToList() because of that. I hope that explains my issue.

Comment: Can you post code related to ContextFactory. You are getting your DBContext from it, does it create that context each time or it is cached.

Comment: Add a GUID field in your ContextFactory and log that on each Get, and see if they are same. See this link for more test methods http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/

Comment: Great suggestion. I think I can see where the problem might have been since the start. I have updated my question with the ContextFactory class contents. It's indeed returning a new instance for every get() call. I think I would have to alter it's implementation and make it a singleton class. The Unity Container itself is asked to register ContextFactory as a singleton but the Model I'm returning from it is unique on per call basis, which it should not be.